# Receive data via REST between two databases on two different servers

Tags: rest, xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojo.gridx

I have one Lotus DB (db1) on one server and second lotus db (db2) on another server. 
How can I receive data from db1 to db2 via REST service (REST is configured in db1 to receive data from view in db1)?
I think the task must be clear, but I can't find a simple solution to this task :(

Comment: When you have NSF based databases on 2 IBM Domino servers, REST might be the least efficient way to move data. If they should have the same content (or a subset) use replication. It handles all error conditions for you. NRPC and native methods are another alternative. Saves you from translating data types back and forth

Answer (score 1):

Use REST service's property `databaseName` with `!!` between server and database path:

```xml
<xe:restService id="restService2" pathInfo=...>
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewItemFileService 
            databaseName="Server01!!Test/db1.nsf"
            viewName="viewInDb1"
            ...>
        </xe:viewItemFileService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's helped me.

Comment: One more question: If I nave no-Lotus Base with REST service - how can I recive data from it? Via Dojo?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the URL:

```
 var host = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getHeader("Host");
var path = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath();
var page = "/RESTServiceProvider.xsp/hotSheets?rName=AarionPerez";

var url = "http://" + host + path + page;
var url:java.net.URL = new java.net.URL(url);
var urlconn:java.net.URLConnection = url.openConnection();
var reader:java.io.BufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(urlconn.getInputStream()));
var inputLine;
var inJson = "";
    while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
        inJson += inputLine;
    }
    reader.close();
```

This is a call from a NSF, but you can put a non-NSF URL in and get a response. You may need to pass in authentication as well.

Comment: I would suggest to use the Apache HTTP client - takes care of status code, long responses etc